# Foreach 2х массивов

Tags: php, foreach, mysql

Задача, есть 2 массива, в одном каждый элемент массива, картинка, во втором каждый элемент массива, строка текстовая. Нужно реализовать сортировку, так, что бы потом можно было записать это все в бд - 1 картинка = 1 строка текста ( по порядку ).

массив - $images

массив - $text

Нужно эти 2 массива, перебрать и записать в бд, в колонки с картинками - картинки, и к ним в колонке для текста - текст.

Comment: Пример по существу пожалуйста. пример массива и прочее. Что пытались сделать сами и что не получилось ? пока могу посоветовать смотреть в сторону [array_combine](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-combine.php)

Comment: отредактировал

Comment: структуру массивов покажите а не названия переменных

Comment: **/me борется с идеей выразить свои эмоции с помощью оскорблений**

мало данных, пример массивов.... что за $images $text. пример массива выглядит так:

    array('img1.jpg','img2.jpg','img3.jpg');

или так:

    [key1: 'v1',key2: 'v2',key3: 'v3'];

но вовсе не именем переменной в вашем коде.

Comment: Перебирая первый(бОльший) массив foreach можно использовать $value2 = next($array2) чтобы одновременно двигаться по второму массиву.

Answer (score 1):

Соглашусь с [@eicto](/users/11304/eicto) и [@zhenyab](/users/6147/zhenyab): если вы хотите, чтобы вас лучше поняли, приводите примеры входных и выходных данных.

Вообще, если под "картинка" вы понимаете имя или путь к файлу с изображением, то для таких целей (имеется ввиду сортировка нескольких массивов сразу) есть специальная функция, [array_multisort()](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-multisort.php) называется. Используется крайне просто

```
array_multisort($images, $text);
```

Если я правильно понял вашу задачу, то на выходе вы получите то, о чем писали.